# How to change the colour and attribute of some text inside comments of xskak loop

Tags: chess

How to change the colour and font size of a part of the text inside comments; using the following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{}
\makeatother
\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{%
\ifthenelse
  {\equal{#1}{N}}%knight move
  {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}%
  {\ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{}}% castling
    {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}%
    {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\newchessgame
\hidemoves{
1. d4 e6 2. e4 d5 3. Nc3 c5 \xskakcomment{the next move determines the progress of the game}
}
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}
\chessboard[normalboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,  markstyle=\dots\, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}
  \xskakget{lan}
  \xskakget{nag}
  \par
  }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\xskakcomment{the \textcolor{red}{next} {\Huge move} determines the progress of the game}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this solution? Especially the integration into the given code should be mentioned.

Comment: @TeXnician, this line is taken from the OP's code. I've just added `\textcolor{red}{next} {\Huge move}`

Comment: That would be worth mentioning. You post was so short that it appeared in the Low quality queue.